# Eigen matrix slicing based on an index vector

Tags: c++, eigen, eigen3

I am using a linear algebra package, Eigen, for my C++ project. Now the Eigen release is 3.3.7. The Eigen official website provides an example on slicing matrix which is exactly what I am looking for. However, from the upper corner of the page, it indicates that it is a feature for 3.3.9.

So I have two questions
1) Is there any alternative in the current release (3.3.7) to slice a matrix as below?
2) Where can I find 3.3.9? It seems that GitHub doesn't have 3.3.9 yet.

Eigen [Link](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/group__TutorialSlicingIndexing.html) 3.3.9

```
std::vector<int> ind{4,2,5,5,3};
MatrixXi A = MatrixXi::Random(4,6);
cout << "Initial matrix A:\n" << A << "\n\n";
cout << "A(all,ind):\n" << A(all,ind) << "\n\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

You're referring to the devel branch, so the future 3.4 version which is currently tagged as 3.3.90 (90 not 9). You can get it from the web site [front page](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org), third line.

Comment: Do we know when 3.4 is going to release?  I also tried use a vector<bool> as index, and it seems that it translate bool to 0,1 ...